# Can I compose a function that has an implicit argument?

Tags: scala

I'm playing around with higher kinds, and I'm trying to use compose.  I've got the following code:

```
def p2( a : Int) = a + 2
def p3( a : Int) = a + 3
val p5 = p2 _ compose p3
def pn3[T](n : T)(implicit ev : Numeric[T]) = ev.plus(n, ev.fromInt(3))
val pn5 = p2 _ compose pn3
```

It all works until the last line:

```
error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: Numeric[T]
```

Which makes sense but how do I tell it, "I want `Numeric[Int]`!"

Comment: Seriously, @aioobe ?  You edited out my reference to famous author and software type-theorist Alexandre Dumas?  Sigh.

Comment: heh. I had no idea. I did it for *you* though. I've seen questions with better wording than that get closed...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trial and error ;)

```
val pn5 = p2 _ compose pn3[Int]
```